# Django model formset questions

Tags: django, django-models

how do you use model formset in Django? When you do this:

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
OrderFormset = modelformset_factory(Order)
formset = OrderFormset()
```

formset has all Orders from DB...

How do I limit them for example to profile.orders (Profila is connected to Order with FK)?

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By passing a queryset argument

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
OrderFormset = modelformset_factory(Order)
formset = OrderFormset(queryset=Order.objects.filter(name="myorder"))
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-custom-queryset

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use [inline formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

> Inline formsets is a small abstraction
>   layer on top of model formsets. These
>   simplify the case of working with
>   related objects via a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

`czarchaic` got it right. I am just trying to modify it to your needs exactly:

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
OrderFormset = modelformset_factory(Order)
user_profile = request.user.get_profile()
formset = OrderFormset(queryset=user_profile.order_set.all())
```